# Java Resource superclass injected objects are null

Tags: java

I am using Java 1.7. and `javax.inject.Inject`.

When I have just one class (i.e. no abstracted functionality to the superclass), it works perfectly. However, when I create a superclass, then the superclasses injected member variables are `null`.

For example, below.

the following is not null:

```
TripServiceLocal tripService;
```

But these are null:

```
@Inject
JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

@Inject
MemberServiceLocal memberService;

@Inject
private TravelAgencyFacadeLocal travelAgencyFacade;
```

**Question**

Why are the super classes injected member variables null?  How do I solve this?

I have the following REST resource:

**IndexResource.java**

```
@Path("index")
@Api(tags={"IndexResource"})
public class IndexResource extends BaseResource {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(IndexResource.class.getName());

    @Inject
    TripServiceLocal tripService;

    /**
     * My Trips as travel agent
     */
    @GET
    @Path("mytrips")
    @ApiOperation(value="Returns the list of 'My Trips' trips. If person who logged in is a travel agent, then get all trips belonging to them.")
    @ApiResponses({
            @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
    })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response getMyTrips(@HeaderParam("Authorization") String token, @Context HttpServletRequest request)  {
        TripSummaryResponse tripSummaryResponse = new TripSummaryResponse();
        try {
            AgentDTO agentDTO = getAgentDTO(token, request);
            tripSummaryResponse.setAgentDTO(agentDTO);

            Set<TripSummaryDTO> myTrips = new HashSet<TripSummaryDTO>();
            List<TripSummaryDTO> requesterTripsInbox = tripService.findTripsForMemberDashboard(agentDTO.getMemberId());
            List<TripSummaryDTO> agentTrips = tripService.findTripsForAgent(agentDTO.getMemberId(), Long.parseLong(agentDTO.getAgentObject().getAgentID()));
            myTrips.addAll(requesterTripsInbox);
            myTrips.addAll(agentTrips);
            tripSummaryResponse.setTrips(myTrips);

            tripSummaryResponse.setStatus("success");
            return Response.ok().entity(tripSummaryResponse).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.severe(e.getMessage());
            tripSummaryResponse.setStatus("fail");
            tripSummaryResponse.getMessages().add(new UIMessages(UIMessages.MessageType.ERROR, e.toString()+": "+e.getLocalizedMessage()));
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(tripSummaryResponse).build();
        }
    }

}
```

**BaseResource.java**

```
public class BaseResource {

    @Inject
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Inject
    MemberServiceLocal memberService;

    @Inject
    private TravelAgencyFacadeLocal travelAgencyFacade;

    /**
     * Gets an agent from a jwt
     *
     * @param jwtToken
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected AgentDTO getAgentDTO(String jwtToken, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        AgentDTO agentDTO = new AgentDTO();
        try {
            String token = jwtTokenUtil.getJwtToken(jwtToken);
            String userName = jwtTokenUtil.extractUserName(token);
            Member member = memberService.getMemberByUserName(userName);
            AgentObject agentObject = (AgentObject)request.getSession().getAttribute("travelagentobject");
            if (agentObject == null || !agentObject.getMemberID().equals(Long.toString(member.getId()))) {
                agentObject = travelAgencyFacade.getAgentDetails(member.getId());
                request.getSession().setAttribute("travelagentobject", agentObject);
            }
            agentDTO.setAgentObject(agentObject);
            agentDTO.setMemberId(member.getId());
            agentDTO.setUserName(userName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Error trying to get the agent from the jwt token. "+e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
        }
        return agentDTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is doing the injecting? (e.g. Spring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many good reasons to [not use direct field injection](https://blog.indrek.io/articles/to-field-inject-or-not-to/). If you make these final and use constructor injection then you can still throw `@Inject` at the subclass constructor. If, like me, you don't like the additional boilerplate, see that link for reasons to put up with it.

```
public abstract class BaseResource {
  private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
  private final MemberServiceLocal memberService;
  private final TravelAgencyFacadeLocal travelAgencyFacade;

  @Inject
  protected BaseResource(
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
    MemberServiceLocal memberService,
    TravelAgencyFacadeLocal travelAgencyFacade) {...}
}

public class IndexResource extends BaseResource {
  @Inject
  public IndexResource(
    JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
    MemberServiceLocal memberService,
    TravelAgencyFacadeLocal travelAgencyFacade) { super(...); }
}
```